# Between two event listeners: How do I pass my function without using trigger()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Please check out my diagram, and the pseudo-code below.  I'm trying to figure out how to pass a function between two event listeners.

Basically, I want to execute some code if "Availability" is less than 0, OR when a user clicks "confirm" in a bootstrap dialog.  If the Availability is greater than 0, you'll get the special bootstrap dialog.

I'm trying to avoid writing the same code twice.  I'm also trying to avoid using trigger `$("#btnConfirm").trigger("click", fn1);` --- my assumption is that there is a sexier way, like a callback, or something...

So.... how do I get the code I want to execute into the other 'button click' event listener  --OR-- how do I return "btnConfirm" back to the event listener that called the dialog?

[image]

```
$("#Select").on("change", function(e) {

  fn1 = function() {
    //stuff I want to do
  };

  //a check that must be passed
  currAvail = $("#Availability").val();

  if (currAvail > 0) {
    //show a message, "Are you sure you want to make the thing?"
    //if YES, execute fn1()
    //fn1() needs to be available to btnConfirm click listener
    // use trigger("click", fn1) ????



  } else {

    //execute the code
    fn1();

  };

});

$("#btnConfirm").on("click", function(e, param1) {

  //Ok, well, they said YES...
  //so I need to execute fn1();


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the requirement is to call `fn1()` in both cases, you can separate the logic out into a method and call when it is needed

```
function fn1() {
  //code to execute on no goes here
}
$("#Select").on("change", function(e) {
  let currAvail = $("#Availability").val();
  if (currAvail > 0) {
    //show modal window
  } else {
    //execute the code
    fn1();
  };
});
$("#btnConfirm").on("click", function(e, param1) {
  fn1()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just move the function definition to outside the `change` callback?

```
$("#Select").on("change", function(e) {
  //a check that must be passed
  currAvail = $("#Availability").val();

  if (currAvail > 0) {
    //show a message, "Are you sure you want to make the thing?"
    //if YES, execute fn1()
    //fn1() needs to be available to btnConfirm click listener
    // use trigger("click", fn1) ????

  } else {
    //execute the code
    fn1();
  };
});

$("#btnConfirm").on("click", function(e, param1) {
  //Ok, well, they said YES...
  //so I need to execute fn1();
});

// Function move to here.
function fn1() {
  //stuff I want to do
};
```